# Finger print scan & get its image in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, ios8, fingerprint

I want to integrate finger print scanning in my app. For that I can use LAContext to integrate default Finger print authentication which is supported after iPhone 5s. But I want the image of finger print and want to use the same in app. 
How can I do that ?
Is there any way in the same SDK or any third party available for that ?

-Thanks in advance,
 Aakil.